# Tomcat cayenne fetching transient object from relationship

Tags: java

Why is my persistent object returning transient objects when fetching via a relationship?

```
ObjectContext context = BaseContext.getThreadObjectContext();

// Delete some employee schedules
List<EmployeeSchedule> employeeSchedules = this.getEmployeeSchedules();
for (EmployeeSchedule employeeSchedule : employeeSchedules) {
  context.deleteObject(employeeSchedule);
}

// Add new schedules
for(int i = 0; i < someCondition; i++) {
   EmployeeSchedule employeeSchedule = context.newObject(EmployeeSchedule.class);
   addToEmployeeSchedules(employeeSchedule);
}

context.commitChanges();

List<EmployeeSchedule> es = getEmployeeSchedules();  // returns transient objects
```

It is inserting the data correctly into the database.  Would this be an issue with stale data in the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in case someone else get tripped up by this in the future.

I have a many-to-many relationship.
Employee - EmployeeSchedule - Schedule

According to the delete rules here: http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.0/delete-rules.html, I set the fields employee_id and schedule_id in the EmployeeSchedule to Nullify rule on delete.

I also had to configure the join table EmployeeSchedule by making employee_id and schedule_id primary keys in the Modeler and checking the "to Dep PK" checkbox in the employee and schedule dbEntity.

Relevant links: http://objectstyle.org/cayenne/lists/cayenne-user/2004/02/0017.html
http://grokbase.com/t/cayenne/user/085d70sysk/to-dep-checkbox-was-one-to-many-problem